# How to implement Persistent storage in android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persistent Data Storage in Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772147/persistent-data-storage-in-android-development)

I want to implement persistent storage in android application.
Can anybody tell me, how i can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should look into this subject here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You might use [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). There are plenty of tutorials over the internet.