# Listview Get Empty when I click back button

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am storing all the value in `arraylist` when button is clicked and when it get added in `listview` but the problem is that when I go again in that activity or page my `listview` is empty I cant see any data in my listview.
                here i have link which [here i have search][1]
I have 6 text which i have to pass many activity of `listview` how can i achieve it.And those text should be store in `listview` of each activity*

I have two activities, in the main one I have a text field and two buttons, the user can enter text in the text field.

When clicking the add button,text will be added to some `ArrayList`.

When clicking show in list button a new activity with its own fragment should open showing a `listview` that contains the names that the user has entered.

*I used ArrayAdapter and this is working fine. When I am in the list activity and when I click the back button of the device everything goes fine and the data in the ArrayList is not lost. If I click show in list again I will find the old data I entered at the first time. But, if I click the back icon provided by Android at the top left of the device screen, the ArrayListbecomes empty and when I click show in list the listview shows as empty.*

```
      ListView listView;
        Spinner spinner, spinner1;
        public static String item, quantity, timee, datee;
        // ArrayList<Used_Item> used_items;
        public static Used_Item used_item;
        Button date, time, add;
        Used_Item_adapter used_item_adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_used_item);
            initiaLizer();
            // used_items = new ArrayList<>();
            GlobalStatic.used_items = new ArrayList<>();

    //        used_item = new Used_Item(item, quantity, datee, timee);
    //       GlobalStatic.used_items.add(used_item);
            used_item_adapter = new Used_Item_adapter(this, GlobalStatic.used_items);
            listView.setAdapter(used_item_adapter);
            add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    used_item = new Used_Item(item, quantity, datee, timee);
                    Log.e("UsedItem", used_item.toString());
                    GlobalStatic.used_items.add(used_item);
                    used_item_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        public void initiaLizer() {

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner);
            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner1);
            ArrayAdapter adapterr = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fooditem, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterr);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.quantity, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    quantity = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.e("Quantity", quantity);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.e("ITEMM", item);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date);
            time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontime);

            assert date != null;
            date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select");
                }
            });


            assert time != null;
            time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TimePicker mTimePicker = new TimePicker();
                    mTimePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select time");
                }
            });


        }

        public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                date.setText("" + String.valueOf(year) + "/" + String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day));
                datee = "" + String.valueOf(year) + "/" + String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day);
                Log.e("DATEAEA", datee);
            }
        }

        public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                time.setText(" " + String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " : " + String.valueOf(minute));
                timee = " " + String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " : " + String.valueOf(minute);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

    Here is my adapter class
     ArrayList<Used_Item> used_items;
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public Used_Item_adapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Used_Item> objects) {
            super(context, R.layout.adapter, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.used_items = objects;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder ;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                Used_Item used_item= getItem(position);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false);
                holder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roti);
                holder.item.setText(used_item.getItem());

                holder.used = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.used);
                holder.used.setText(used_item.getQuantity());

                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                holder.date.setText(used_item.getDate());

                holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timee);
                holder.time.setText(used_item.getTime());

            }else
            {
                holder=(Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            return convertView;

        }

        public static class Holder {
            private TextView item;
            private TextView used;
            private TextView date;
            private TextView time;


 *I don't Understand how can I save my data in listview so when i go on that page it is present
```

please any help
    Any help can be appreciated*

Comment: You're looking to persist the data which can later be loaded when you open the screen again at later point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent Data Storage in Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772147/persistent-data-storage-in-android-development)

Answer (score 0):

You use `convertView.getTag` but don't use `convertView.setTag(holder);`
So, i think your code should be like this

```
if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            Used_Item used_item= getItem(position);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false);
            holder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roti);
            holder.item.setText(used_item.getItem());

            holder.used = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.used);
            holder.used.setText(used_item.getQuantity());

            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.date.setText(used_item.getDate());

            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timee);
            holder.time.setText(used_item.getTime());
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else
        {
            holder=(Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you are going back using device back button then it calls `onPause()` and `onStop()` but if you are going back using back using back icon of android it calls `onDestroy()`.

You can handle android back icon by overriding this function...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Here you can do what you want
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```